# How do I add a ceiling fan to a 3-way switch?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, multiway-switch

About three months ago, I hired an electrician to change some of the circuits in my house, and two of the circuits were supposed to be able to add a ceiling fan on a 3 way switch.  In one room, all of the receptacles were switched on the bottom, live on top (no switch needed), and on a 3 way switch.  In the other, none of the receptacles were switched, and there was a 3 way switch already in place.

After the work was done, none of the receptacles in the first room are switched, and both were supposed to be able to add a ceiling fan with light kit to the 3 way switch.

After installing both fans (didn’t it myself, as the contractor couldn’t), I can only get power to either the fan or the light at one time.  So, here is what I know to be true about this:

1. At the fan box, I have what looks like 14-3 as it is white, black, and red with a bare ground.
2. From the fan, I have a white, black and blue wire, with a green ground on the mounting bracket.
3. It looks like two single pole switches were used, but I’m not 100% sure.  One of the switches stil has the upc on it, which leads me to a pass and Seymour single pole switch.
4. I have connected ground to ground, and white to white.  When I connect black (box) to black (fan), and red (box) to blue (fan), the light kit works.  When I connect black (box) to blue (fan), and red (box) to black (fan), the fan motor works.

After that, I am lost.  I’ve never run into a 3 way circuit being run by two single pole switches, so that is throwing me a bit.

Am I making the proper connections, or am I missing something?  Any help or insight at this point is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?

Comment: Do these suspect switches bear "ON" and "OFF" labels or are they unmarked?

Comment: So you are doing 3-way, which means you have 2 switch locations presumably on opposite sides of the room.  Can you describe or photograph the wiring in those switch locations?

Comment: Or are you trying to have 2 switches where there normally would be 1 switch? 1 for the fan, and one for the light?